# Importing trie-search into angular

Tags: typescript

I would like to use the trie-search library in my angular project. However I tried as much as I can to create .d.ts file without much success ( constructor errors, function errors).
My last attempt went something like this

```
// index.d.ts

declare module 'trie-search'{

  class TrieSearch {
      constructor();
      addFromObject( valueField:any ): void;
  }

  type TrieSearchFactory = () => TrieSearch
  


}
```

but it came out with an error as well;
the module function signature works like this

```
var TrieSearch = function (keyFields, options)
```

and the usage starts with

```
const trie-search = new TrieSearch()
```

Anybody have any ideas on how to create the appropriate .d.ts file or alternatively a default angular service to implement the trie search

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to define a [constructor](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#constructors) with arguments just fine:

```js
declare module 'trie-search'{

  class TrieSearch {
      constructor(keyFields: string | string[], options: any);
      addFromObject( valueField:any ): void;
  }

  export = TrieSearch;
}
```

I also noticed you're not actually saying what's exported, so you need that `export =` statement. *(the way that module exports its stuff, you can't use `export class TrieSearch { ...`)*

You can also look around on NPM (or Google) for alternative libraries. There seem to be quite a few Trie-related libraries, some even written in TypeScript.

Comment: Thanks Kelvin, the solution works beautifully . ( I tweaked the constructor to make keyfields and options optional ) and added ""esModuleInterop" : true" in the tsconfig.json. Module can be imported by putting "import TrieSearch from 'trie-search';" in the module in question.